# My NSDate countdown timer changes when I change views

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdate

I have a countdown timer from the current date until 10 minutes have passed.

It counts down completely fine when I'm on the view, but when I change views and come back, then the timer stops, could anybody point me in the right direction?

```
-(void)updateCountdown {

dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSUInteger unitFlags = NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateComponants = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:startingDate toDate:endingDate options:0];

NSInteger minutes = [dateComponants minute];
NSInteger seconds = [dateComponants second];

NSString *countdownText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Free Check: %ld:%ld", (long)minutes, (long)seconds];
timeLabel.text = countdownText;

NSLog (@"Startdate is %@", startingDate);
NSLog(@"Enddate is %@", endingDate);

//Attempt at saving the time but I guess this only saves the text?
NSString * saveStringTime = timeLabel.text;
NSUserDefaults * defaultsTime = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaultsTime setObject:saveStringTime forKey:@"saveStringTime"];
[defaultsTime synchronize];

[self performSelector:@selector(updateCountdown) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```

I think I need something in my ViewDidLoad to get whatever time it was and put that back in?

Thank you

Comment: Does your view controller get deallocated when you leave and realloced when you come back?

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I check this?

Comment: You can check that by implementing dealloc and putting a log in it, and/or put a log in viewDidLoad and see if it's called again when you go back to the controller.

Comment: Even though the code shown isn't using `dateFormatter`, please note `YYYY` should be `yyyy`.  See the Fixed Formats section in the [Date Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW13) (look for "A common mistake is to use YYYY...").  Also see http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the "savedStringTime" in viewWillAppear to resume from the "savedTime". Since viewDidLoad will get invoked only if the view is loaded to memory, viewDidLoad will not get invoked when the user navigates back to the same view(since view is still in memory).

To get proper working, Invoke your method to save the time in "viewWillDisappear" and in "viewWillAppear" check if the "savedStringTime" is available, if yes then resume it or else start a fresh counter.